# How do you redirect wget response to standard out?

Tags: linux, wget, stdout

I have a `crontab` that `wget`s a PHP page every five minutes (just to run some the PHP code), and I want to send the output of the request to standard out, while sending the normal `wget` output to `/dev/null` (or otherwise hide it).  I couldn't find it in the `wget` manual.

I'm looking for something like:

```
wget -o stdout http://whatever.com/page.php > /dev/null
```

Anyone know?

Comment: Mistitled, should be "How do you redirect wget to null?".

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone I think it is titled correctly.  I wanted the thing that is `wget`-ed to go to a `stdout`, and the normal `stdout` to go to `null` (i.e. ignore what it usually prints, and instead print the response body).

Comment: Oh!  I stand corrected.  I have started using `wget http://example.com/page.php -qO-`  (That's a capital Oh.)  That standard-outputs ONLY the response body.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: In case it helps someone (as per how I landed here), On a terminal of an AWS Cloud9 its wget -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname -q       which gets me the public DNS (as doing web dev)

Comment: Dealing with ampersands, etc. in the URL (e.g. `https://superuser.com/questions?tab=newest&page=542&pagesize=50`): See e.g. *[How can I download weblinks using wget which do not end with .html?](https://superuser.com/questions/543386)*

Answer (score 307, accepted):

`wget -O - http://whatever.com/page.php > /dev/null`

or, if you want to redirect standard error output also:

`wget -O - http://whatever.com/page.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

or, for codegolf :-)

`wget -O-`

Comment: You may want to add `-nv` to avoid the progress indicator overwriting the output.

Comment: This approach has a problem - if response status is not 200, it doesn't print body. Any thoughts to resolve it?

Comment: See answer from Martin Wang - you need to add -q to actually see the output.

Comment: I want to output IP address from website so i just put `wget  -q -O -  https://api.ipify.org` and it's output it to the shell .

Comment: In the more general case, shouldn't the URL be quoted (or otherwise)? In case it contains something the shell (say, on Linux or Windows) is very interested in, such as ampersands or semicolons. Sample: `https://superuser.com/questions?tab=newest&page=542&pagesize=50`. Used as is on Linux, this leads to output like "`[1] 9663 [2] 9664`" (9663 and 9664 are presumably process IDs) - the effective URL used by wget will be cut off - `https://superuser.com/questions?tab=newest`

Comment: @PeterMortensen well yeah of course, you have to quote URLs with special characters :-) With simple urls though, noone will bother with quoting. This is the same with filenames. This is the basic shellwork though, isn't related to wget in any way.

Comment: This redirects all output to /dev/null: **wget -O - http://whatever.com/page.php > /dev/null**

You want the following (to redirect stderror only): **wget -O - http://whatever.com/page.php 2> /dev/null**

Answer (score 247):

A simpler version

```
wget -qO- http://example.com
```

equivalent to

```
wget -q -O - http://example.com
```

where

- `-q` turns off the output of log, including error information
- `-O -`, equivlalent to `-O /dev/stdout`, means dump the web page to a file named `/dev/stdout`.

Comment: The first one works with BusyBox's wget, which is very helpful. I don't think it likes having a space after the `O`

Comment: `wget --quiet --output-document=/dev/stdout http://localhost:8080/commands/srvr | grep "server_state"` to show [zookeeper state](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.5/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_adminserver)

Answer (score 21):

```
wget -qO /dev/null http://whatever.com/page.php
```

- `-q` to make it quiet
- `-O /dev/null` to ignore the page contents

Answer (score 13):

You can also try:

```
wget -q -O - http://whatever.com/page.php > /dev/null
```

the `-q` will make it "quiet"

Or have the file go to some temp html page that you don't mind having. whatever.com/tempFile.html

Answer (score 3):

```
wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/
```

Comment: It works on my mac with wget 1.12.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation about what your code does?

Comment: -O means "write output to this file"