# How can I download weblinks using wget which do not end with .html?

Tags: windows, command-line, wget, gnu

I want to download this webpage using [Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) on Windows 7:

`http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.deviceListView.xhr.flowtype-NEW.deviceGroupType-Cellphone.paymentType-postpaid.packageType-undefined.html?commitmentTerm=24&taxoStyle=SMARTPHONES&showMoreListSize=1000`

I am using this command to do this:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P /Downloads/AT&T_2013-01-29/ http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.deviceListView.xhr.flowtype-NEW.deviceGroupType-Cellphone.paymentType-postpaid.packageType-undefined.html?commitmentTerm=24&taxoStyle=SMARTPHONES&showMoreListSize=1000
```

I am getting "taxostyle not defined", "commitmentterm not defined" or "recognizble method error".

Comment: This is a very common occurrence when using Wget. Isn't there a more canonical question about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ampersands ( `&` ) and a question mark in your URL.

I am not sure how your Windows shell handles that. It probably depends on what you are using. (Cmd.exe? [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), [Hamilton C-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton_C_shell) for Windows, [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)/[Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)?)

Regardless, many of those will try to parse those and you will end up with Wget getting a different result than you expect. You would either need to escape those characters (how depends on the shell), or use `"` marks.

If I use
`wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off "http://www.att.com/shop/wireless/devices/smartphones.deviceListView.xhr.flowtype-NEW.deviceGroupType-Cellphone.paymentType-postpaid.packageType-undefined.html?commitmentTerm=24&taxoStyle=SMARTPHONES&showMoreListSize=1000"`
in the Bash 3 shell on [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) (notice the added quotes around the download URL) then the command does seem to work. (It downloads three directories, 2.ecom.attccc.com, 3.ecom.attccc.com, and [www.att.com](http://www.att.com))

---

As an alternative, you can put your URL in a FILE as it is (one in a line) and pass an additional `-i FILE` parameter to wget instead of URL itself.

Another case to check what is really passed to Wget by your command is `echo` it, like this `echo HERE_IS_URL` and if the output is acceptable, you can replace `echo` with `wget` or pipe it forward with `| wget -i-`.